# Can we get a search and replace tool for the Edit Box?

Tags: feature-request, edits, editor

Sometimes in a large post, the user makes the same small mistake.  It'd sure be nice if we could do a search and replace in the edit box to change the one word or phrase around, multiple times.

Comment: I'd settle for something that removes all instances of "plz"

Comment: I haven't used it, but for those that want something right now, there's [this extension/userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/2209/se-editor-toolkit). I'm on the fence about the feature request, since I'm not sure where I'd put the line between it being useful to certain people and largely irrelevant to most other people.

Comment: I'm not necessarily opposed, but it seems more like a feature that the browser should implement rather than individual websites.

Comment: Seems like a tool that is useful to the editors and and irrelevant to most other people, would still be good to implement.  I've edited thousands of posts, and there were sure time this would have been nice.

Comment: @bemace, seems like it'd be hard for the browser to limit to just the edit box, but I'm going to try the extension that Tim mentioned and see.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I agree, I was just coming at it from the usability angle. I'm trying to picture how you might introduce such a feature in a way that those who would benefit from it would know to use it, but make it unobtrusive to everyone else. Since there's no natural separation between power editors and normal folk it's a bit hard in this case.

Comment: @jonsca: There is [no end to such lists](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html).

Comment: Just get the Grammarly browser extension.